# vb.net Display database record in a button

Tags: mysql, vb.net

my code is not showing any records, what could be the problem here
or is it possible to display record on a button?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form4

Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db"
        con.Open()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate"
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        Button1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString
    End While

    dr.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What did you expect it to show?  What happens when you step into the code with the debugger?

Comment: i expect it to show database record automatically without click but, its' not

Answer (score 1):

The connection object you're initializing in the `Button1_Click` method doesn't seem to be provided any connection string. I'm afraid the code you provided will through an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Don't leave the connection hanging around in this way, specially with MySql. 
Remove the useless creation of a connection in the form load and create the connection only in the button click with the appropriate connection string

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate"
    Using con = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
         con.Open()

         Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
             While dr.Read
                 Button1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString
             End While
         End Using
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The Using Statement will prevent the loss of valuable resource like the connection, the command and the datareader because these objects will be closed and disposed immediately on tue End Using line also in case of exceptions

As a side note, your code will show in the button just the last value extracted from the table candidate because in your reader.Read loop you continue to assign the button text with the value of the current record until you reach the last record. So probably there is something to be rethinked here